# angularJs validate form binded to an array

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have form with 3 different tabs per env (DEV,UAT and PROD)
In my code I have something like:

```
<form name="baseForm">
...
<input class="form-control" name="url" ng-model="wsConfig.config[env].url" ng-required="true" type="text"/>
</form>
```

Before submiting this form i am checking if it's correctly filled in using baseForm.$invalid value.
My problem is that validation works only for current tab, how can I force angular to perform validation for entire configuration: DEV,UAT and PROD?

Comment: Is the HTML for other tabs not there when you validate?

Comment: Same html is used for other tabs, I am just executing such method setEnv('dev'), setEnv('uat'), setEnv('prod') when going to another tab. setEnv is setting value in $scope.env. Problem is that I can fill only current tab, without filling required fields in 2 other tabs and validation will be performed only for current config['dev'], (if env = 'dev'). Validation for config['uat'] and config['prod'] will be skipped.